# Using ISBLANK formula to write a variance

Tags: openoffice-calc

I've got a formula or a plan £ in `C4`, and the actual £ to be entered in `D4` cell. `E4` contains the formula `D4-C4`.

I would like `E4` to be blank until both `C4` and `D4` have values.

Comment: `ISBLANK` only returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`. You probably want to use `IF` instead as it includes a T or F check in the formula already.

Answer (score 2):

You want e4 to remain blank until data is entered in d4?
try entering into e4:

```
=if(d4="","",d4-c4)
```

If you could have a blank in c4 then try

```
=if(or(c4="",d4=""),"",d4-c4)
```

If you're using open office swap the commas for semicolons ie

```
=if(or(c4="";d4="");"";d4-c4)
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. No I want e4 to remain blank Untill data is entered into d4. The formula for e4 will be d4-c4

Comment: @Simon Then change the formula he gave you to `=IF(D4="","",D4-C4)`. It really is a simple IF formula.

Comment: I've have entered this but it still comes up with err:508. Would it matter I'm using open office ... It's identical to excel.

Comment: Edited. This works on my libre office calc. error 508 is a missing bracket. Try copying and pasting my edited solution.

Comment: @MrPurple Try editing again, your edit didn't make sense so I rolled it back.

Comment: Also, if you are using Open Office then I believe it uses semi-colons (;) instead of commas (,). Try `=IF(D4="";"";D4-C4)`.

Answer (score 1):

The formula in Excel for `E4` should be `=IF(OR(ISBLANK(C4),ISBLANK(D4)),"",D4-C4)`.  For OpenOffice, replace the commas with semi-colons.

Comment: @michael I've entered your into excel and it works fine. But has error 508 in open office. First time I've ever known open iffice not be the same as excel. Not sure what you mean about copying my editored solution... I'm new to this site tonight.

Comment: @Simon Use `=IF(D4="","",D4-C4)` for Excel. Use `=IF(D4="";"";D4-C4)` for Open Office.

Comment: @MichaelFrank - Brian's answer is correct (the question asks for both C4 and D4 to have values before E4 is displayed.  Your substitute formula doesn't do that.  The issue is that the OP stated the wrong application.  The commas need to be replaced with semi-colons for this to work with OO.

Comment: @michael it's worked fine. Works perfect, and I've adapted to % to. Brill!

Comment: The "err: 508" bit should've tipped me off that it wasn't Excel we were working with here. @fixer1234, you've lived up to your name - thanks!